# Update field from c# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, indexing

I have a document collection like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4fb21439f31dfd122ce39c4a"),
    "Name" : "Freelander 2",
    "Manufacture" : "Landrover"
}
```

I am using the C# driver, and want to check whether the "Name" field exists; if it does not, I need to update it from the code.  Can someone help on this?  Please share sample code because I am a newbie to mongoDB.

Comment: to check "Name" exist or not ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **[exists](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24exists)** operator:

```
db.myCollection.find( { Name: { $exists: true } } );
```

Using the C# driver, the equivalent would be something like this:

```
IMongoQuery query = Query.Exists("Name", true)
var results = myCollection.Find(query);
```

To set a value if it doesn't exist, you can use an **Update** statement like this:

```
IMongoQuery query = Query.Exists("name", true);
IMongoUpdate update = Update.Set("Name", "newvalue");
myCollection.Update(query, update);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to update all documents that don't have a Name field to the same value. You can do that in the mongo shell like this:

```
> db.test.update({Name:{$exists:false}}, {$set:{Name:"xyz"}}, false, true)
```

You can do the same thing in C# like this:

```
var query = Query.Exists("Name", false);
var update = Update.Set("Name", "xyz");
collection.Update(query, update, UpdateFlags.Multi);
```